# What is the explicit equivalence relation for an adjunction space $X\cup_f Y$

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

> What is the explicit equivalence relation for an adjunction space $X\cup_f Y$ ?

Intuitively, the construction of $X\cup_f Y$ is pretty straightforward: we begin with the data $(X,Y,B\subseteq Y,\, f:B\rightarrow X)$ and form the adjunction space $X\cup_f Y$ by taking the disjoint union of $X$ and $Y$ then identifying points in $B$ with their image in $X$.

My question is about how to formalize this construction. One often sees notation like '$X/A$' when speaking of quotient spaces, but the definition of a quotient space requires an explicit equivalence relation. With notation as in my first paragraph, the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space) actually defines the notation $Y/B$ to be the adjunct space $X\cup_f Y$ where $X$ is a point.

I would like to be able to write something like 
 $$
 X\cup_f Y:= X\coprod Y/\sim,
 $$
but the equivalence relation I worked out seems a bit, well, messy. What I did manage is the following, but it is not so elegant and I feel I must be overthinking things. Here are my thoughts: set $Z= X\coprod Y$ and define the relation $R\subseteq Z\times Z$ by $R=\cup R_i$ where 
 $$
R_1=\bigg\{\big((x,0),(x,0)\big)\,\,|\,\,x\in X\bigg\}
$$
$$
R_2= \bigg\{\big((y,1),(y,1)\big)\,\,|\,\,y\in Y\bigg\}
$$
$$
R_3=\bigg\{\big((x,0),(y,1)\big)\,\,|\,\, y\in B \,\, \text{and}\,\, f(y)=x\bigg\}
$$
$$
R_4=\bigg\{\big((y,1),(x,0)\big)\,\,|\,\, y\in B \,\, \text{and} \,\, f(y)=x\bigg\},
$$
 so then $\alpha\sim \beta\iff (\alpha,\beta)\in R$. With these definitions, I think everything works out but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relation still might not be transitive. For example, when $b(y_1)=b(y_2)=x_1$ for $y_1\neq y_2$, you want $(y_0, 1)\sim (y_1, 1)$. Usually you don't write down all the relations of such an equivalence relation and instead give "generating relations". In this case, they just are
$$\widetilde R = \left\{ \, \Big((x, 0) , (y, 1)\Big) \,\middle|\, \text{$y\in B$ and $f(y)=x$} \,\right\}.$$ Now you define $R$ to be the smallest equivalence relation containing $\widetilde R$. More precisely, denote by $\mathcal R$ the set of all equivalence relations on $X\coprod Y$ containing $\widetilde R$ and set
$$
R = \bigcap_{R'\in\mathcal R} R'.
$$
All you need to do is check that arbitrary intersections of equivalence relations are equivalence relations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. Did you mean to define $R=\bigcap_{\substack{R'\in \mathcal{R} \\ R'\supseteq \tilde R }} R'$? Also, if I set $$R_5=\bigg\{\big((y,1),(y',1)\big)|\,\, f(y)=f(y')\bigg\}$$ and added it to the collection in my question, it seems like the transitivity issue would be fixed?

Comment: I defined $\mathcal R$ to only consist of relations containing $\widetilde R$. Yes, I think adding $R_5$ to your relation should fix transitivity.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I missed that! Thanks again.